# get information from html table using Curl

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

i need to get some information about some plants and put it into mysql table.
My knowledge on Curl and DOM is quite null, but i've come to this:

```
    set_time_limit(0);
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$ch = curl_init ("http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1501/"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;     rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 


$html= str_get_html($data);


$e = $html->find("table", 8);

 echo $e->innertext;
```

now, i'm really lost about how to move in from this point, can you please guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on how you want your table configured (i.e. what columns you want). Scraping that page doesn't seem to be very straightforward due to how the HTML is laid out.

Comment: i need to get the information out of that messy code..... Family, Genus, Species and so on....... and get each one into a column of mysql table

Answer (score 1):

This is a mess.

But at least it's a (somewhat) consistent mess.

If this is a one time extraction and not a rolling project, personally I'd use quick and dirty regex on this instead of simple_html_dom. You'll be there all day twiddling with the tags otherwise.

For example, this regex pulls out the majority of title/data pairs:

```
$pattern = "/<b>(.*?)</b>\s*<br>(.*?)</?(td|p)>/si";
```

You'll need to do some pre and post cleaning before it will get them all though.

I don't envy you having this task...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to wrape this in php ;)

Yes, this is a ugly hack for a ugly html code.

```
<?php
ob_start();
system("
    /usr/bin/env links -dump 'http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1501/' |
    /usr/bin/env perl -lne 'm/((Family|Genus|Species):\s+\w+\s+\([\w-]+\))/ && \
        print $1'
");
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
print $out;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and you would be able to access any element/element's content you wish. Their api is very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

you can try somthing like this.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.digionline.ir/Allprovince/CategoryProducts/cat=10301");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
// get all table rows and rows which are not headers
$table_rows = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tbl-all-product-view"]/tr[@class!="rowH"]');
foreach($table_rows as $row => $tr) {
    foreach($tr->childNodes as $td) {
        $data[$row][] = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', trim($td->nodeValue));
    }
    $data[$row] = array_values(array_filter($data[$row]));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
?>
```